# when does a reputation day begin and end?

Tags: support, reputation

https://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation says ''You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day.''

I am just curiuos: does this mean no more than 200 in any 24h time window, or in a specific one?

In the latter case, it might be useful for strategically minded people to know when this time window begins and ends.

Comment: You may find this helpful: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions

Comment: A link that I'd like to have seen earlier is in fact http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites - it should be placed prominently on the FAQ page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "day" is defined by midnight-to-midnight UTC for all purposes on Stack Exchange sites.